# What is this schematic symbol with two arrows?

Tags: diodes, schematics, symbol

I'm trying to figure out what this schematic symbol is. At first, I thought it was some kind of diode but I don't know if that makes sense. The symbol is highlighted in yellow below:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a badly drawn DIAC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIAC Whether that makes sense in the context of the circuit ... can't tell from here.

Comment: I agree with @BrianDrummond.  Edit your question to show more of the circuit, or tell us what the circuit ought to be doing.

Comment: Is this even an electronic schematic?